# Chat message window not scrolling anymore on new message or page load

Tags: bug, chat

On initial load the chat page used to scroll to the bottom to see the latest message, this doesn't happen anymore and stays at the top.

Initial load:
[image]

When a new message is posted it used to scroll to the latest message, this no longer happens either and I have to scroll down to see the latest post.

After a new message:

[image]

There are no console errors and it even happens in incognito mode where extensions are disabled. I've tried emptying the cache and doing a hard-reload too.

Running it on Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 m on Windows 10

The problem doesn't seem to exist on Chrome Canary (55).

I've just updated to Chrome 61 and this has started happening again.

Comment: I have seen reports before about this, in various rooms, from different users and experienced it my self only a couple of times were it resolved itself. Never managed to repro it consistently.

Comment: @rene Very strange. Nobody I talked to could reproduce it but I can do it consistently.

Comment: Are you on an insane screen size? Zoomed in/out?

Comment: Not really, 1080p, 100% zoom.

Comment: earlier reports [1](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5142976#5142976), [2](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=4885124#4885124)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238246/scrolling-has-stopped-working-in-chat http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280382/chat-in-chrome-on-windows-suddenly-doesnt-scroll-anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed, not sure when or how.

Edit: Fixed again: [AutoScroll on chat exchange doesn't work in chrome 61](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300552/autoscroll-on-chat-exchange-doesnt-work-in-chrome-61)

Comment: And it's back: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300552/autoscroll-on-chat-exchange-doesnt-work-in-chrome-61